# communicate between win service and win app

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, communication

I want to write a windows service that will communicate with my win app and it will run my windows form. How can I do it? If you give me a link of a simple example it will be very good.

I have another question: if I run my win form with windows service and if I don't close my form, it will be closed if the user logs off, is it true?

Comment: Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx for on-machine and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx for cross-machine communication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous options:

- WCF
- .NET Remoting
- shared memory
- named pipes
- plain TCP
- …

What mechanism is the best for your case depends on **tons** of requirements you haven't stated and probably didn't think about. In case you don't have a clue what you need from it, just grab any mechanism that is simple enough and for which you've googled a suitable tutorial and just start coding.

Comment: i want to get the time of login/logout of any users in local network ,now i want to start my service and it runs my app that my app record the time,but if user logs off the app will be closed,and i can't record details any more,is it true???

Answer (score 0):

Ondrej has answered the first part of your question. You also asked:

> I have another question if I run my
>   win form with windows service and if I
>   don't close my form ,it will be close
>   if the user logoff,is it true?

Well, first of all, a service runs without any UI, without any forms. If your service needs to communicate to your user, then that's what you need your app for.

But to answer the question I think you are asking, when a user logs off, any apps that are running will close, but services continue to run.

Comment: what happen for my service if Account properties of serviceProcessInstaller1 be set to user???

Comment: @na.farzane Nothing. Services run in a different, non-interactive *session*.

Comment: what's different between "user" and "localsystem"??

Comment: @na I'm not sure about your question. LOCALSYSTEM is a special account. In very old versions of Windows, services ran under this account. In modern versions, this account still exists but you should not run services under this account.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a windows service is used to perform an operation that must run in a time interval independently. It do not have any UI that shows the progress of the operation.

See the example for a situation where you can use a windows service...

Eg: If a table contains n number of records and each record must be processed. Assume that the   processing might take few minutes, which may result in some kind of time out in asp.net, you can run this process using a windows service. You can set a timer inside the windows service to schedule the row processing (one row at a time and finishes up the entire row processing by the end of the day).